# Existential Quantifier Distributivity in First Order Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

It is well-known that the following formula holds for boolean functions involving free variables:
$$\exists x,P(x)\wedge Q(x)\neq (\exists x_1,P(x_1))\wedge(\exists x_2,Q(x_2)),$$
$$\exists x,P(x) \vee Q(x)=(\exists x_1,P(x_1)) \vee (\exists x_2,Q(x_2)).$$
However, I wonder whether the following holds:
$$\exists x,P(x)\wedge Q(x)= (\exists x_1,P(x_1))\wedge(\exists x_2,Q(x_2))\wedge (x_1=x_2)?$$

Comment: That can't be right: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are free on the RHS but not on the LHS. See the answer below for a correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wonder whether the following formula holds:
$$\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x)) \quad\leftrightarrow\quad (\exists x_1 P(x_1) \wedge \exists x_2 Q(x_2) \wedge  x_1=x_2).\tag1$$
Note that $(1)$ is equivalent to (all the small letters are variables)
$$\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x)) \quad\leftrightarrow\quad (\exists y P(y) \wedge \exists z Q(z) \wedge  p=q).\tag1$$
This assignment and symbolisation key shows that the *open* formula $(1)$ does not have a definite truth value:

$$P(x) \;:=\; x>1\\
Q(x) \;:=\; x<3\\
p \;:=\; 5\\
q_1 \;:=\; 5\\
q_2 \;:=\; 6$$

On the other hand, the open formula
$$\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(y)) \quad\leftrightarrow\quad \exists x P(x)\wedge Q(y) \tag2$$ *is* valid.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit weird, because you introduce $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately from the statement $(x_1=x_2)$. Something better would be to write:
$$\exists x, P(x) \wedge Q(x)= \exists x_1, \exists x_2, P(x_1) \wedge Q(x_2) \wedge (x_1=x_2)$$

Comment: The OPs version is not just a bit weird, it's wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the ambiguity, actually what I was trying to prove is $$\exists x,P(x) \wedge Q(x) \Rightarrow (\exists x, P(x)) \wedge (\exists x, Q(x)).$$